# Given an XML stream how can one know whether it is a binary XML or non binary XML stream?

Tags: .net, xml

I have a stream which contains some XML. The XML may either be encoded using binary XML writer (for instance obtained from `XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter`) or non binary XML writer (like as in `XmlWriter.Create`).

I wish to know which reader to use - the one from `XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader` or the one from `XmlReader.Create`. Of course, I can assume that the XML is non binary and then try and fallback to binary. This is what I do today. But I do not like this approach. I wonder if there is an API, which can guide me in the first place which reader to select.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the data (or the first 100 characters for example) and see if there are any invalid [XML characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Char) and if you don't find any then use the current solution - try `XmlReader.Create` first and fall back to `XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader`.

Comment: Not good. The first byte is 64 and the second is 16. The stream is binary XML.

Comment: I added a more correct solution: if there are no invalid XML characters then it's most likely non-binary XML.